# Airflow 2.4.2 setting up google auth, but nothing is happening still able to use the username/pw login

Tags: airflow, google-oauth, airflow-2.x

I've followed this stack overflow question but I haven't had much luck getting google oauth working with Airflow.
[Is there a way to setup Airflow 2 with Gogle OAuth2 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450200/is-there-a-way-to-setup-airflow-2-with-gogle-oauth2-authentication)

I created a `webserver_config.py` file that looks like this:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
import os
from airflow.models import Variable
import logging

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True  # Checks roles on every login
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True  # allow users who are not already in the FAB DB to register
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"

logging.info(Variable.get("airflow_gcp_client_id"))
logging.info(Variable.get("airflow_gcp_client_secret"))

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "google",
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "whitelist": ['@blah blah'],
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": Variable.get("airflow_gcp_client_id"),
            "client_secret": Variable.get("airflow_gcp_client_secret"),
            "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
            "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "request_token_url": None,
            'redirect_url': 'https://dev-airflow2.net/oauth2callback'
        },
    },
]
```

but nothing changes in my Airflow dev, I can still login with my username/pw.

I've also added this to my `airflow.cfg` file:

```
[google]
auth_callback_route = /oauth2callback

[webserver]

authenticate = True

auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.google_auth
```

Comment: Fixed it... make sure this is actually in the AIRFLOW_HOME directory!